# Memory leaks while using CComBstr and system::string

Tags: c#, visual-c++, memory-leaks, com, bstr

```cpp
    class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMasterStore : 
    
        public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    
        public CComCoClass<CMasterStore, &CLSID_MasterStore>,
    
        public IDispatchImpl<IMasterStore, &IID_IMasterStore, &LIBID_PSLOGLib>
    {
    
    STDMETHODIMP CMasterStore::get_Description(BSTR *pVal)
    {
       *pVal = fbstrDescription.Copy();
        return S_OK;
    }
    
    STDMETHODIMP CMasterStore::put_Description(BSTR newVal)
    {
    
       //SetDirty();
    
       fbstrDescription = newVal;
    
        return S_OK;
    }
    };

/* masterStore used below is a c# class as define here

public ref class **MasterStore**
            {
            public:
               property short Code;
               property String^ Description;*/

IMasterStore* _CurrentMasterStore; //interface
```

This line of code is causing a memory leak:

```cpp
    _CurrentMasterStore->put_Description(static_cast<BSTR>(Marshal::StringToBSTR(masterStore->Description).ToPointer()));
```

If I simply pass string as below, I don't see any memory leaks.

```cpp
    _CurrentMasterRecord->put_Description(L"Test memory leaks");
```

I am unable to find why it is leaking and how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: You allocate a BSTR when you do StringToBSTR. Your code doesn't seem to ever deallocate it.

Comment: can you suggest a possible deallocation code?

Comment: what is fbstrDescription ?

Comment: fbstrDescription this is of CComBstr type

Comment: if `masterStore->Description` is the same code we see, then it allocates once (`copy()`). Then you allocates another time  using `StringToBSTR` (why? this should already be a `BSTR`), so you have a leak since the `CComBstr` will deallocate once automatically on class dtor, but not twice.

Comment: CComBSTR desc = DotnetStringToBstr(masterStore->Description); _CurrentMasterStore->put_Description(desc); 


This is also causing memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

The StringToBSTR method allocates a BSTR on the system heap for the string and assigns puts the string in the newly allocated BSTR and returns the pointer to the string. Memory has been allocated on the caller's behalf and the caller is responsible for releasing the memory when it is no longer needed (presumably after the call to put_Description)

The second approach probably puts the string in the code as a constant literal so no memory is allocated. BSTRs are typically used when the string is going across a process boundary where as the string literal will not cross the process boundary intact. Also a BSTR is not the same a wide string (L'My string') - see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75a504d1-03b7-4592-8dab-b6897585de6a/bstr-bstrt-sysallocstring-wchar-and-passing-parameters-to-wmi-methods?forum=vcgeneral.

I see you are going from managed string (String^) to a BSTR. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp?view=msvc-170 gives a table showing a recommended marshalling method for all kinds of conversions. For System::String^ to BSTR it indicates a marshal_context should be used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-context-class?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170#marshal-as describes the marshal context and provides an example. Applied to your scenario:

```
marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
BSTR* bstrDescription = context->marshal_as<BSTR*>(masterStore->Description);
_CurrentMasterRecord->put_Description(bstrDescription);
delete context;
```

Note that the delete context should free up the BSTR so the put_Description should be making a copy of the BSTR and freeing up its previous value if any. Note that the destructor for MasterStore is also responsible for cleaning up the fbstrDescription. Check out the documentation on CComBSTR and consider using that for fbstrDescription - it encapsulates a lot of the memory management for you.

Comment: I have tried this..


BSTR desc = static_cast<BSTR>(Marshal::StringToBSTR(masterStore->Description).ToPointer());
                           
 _CurrentMasterStore->put_Description(desc);

 ::SysFreeString(desc);

this didn't help..

Comment: I would use the CComBSTR and let the scope manage the manager. Referring to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/programming-with-ccombstr-atl?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170.
    CComBSTR desc(L"Test memory leaks); // Constructor has an overload for widestring
    _CurrentMasterStore->put_Description(desc);
    // When desc falls out of scope its destructor is called that cleans up the memory.
`

Comment: Typo in the last comment - let the scope manage the MEMORY

Comment: Also, change the put_Description to make a copy of the incoming BSTR or it will be pointing at deallocated memory when desc falls out of scope which would be bad.

Comment: CComBSTR desc = DotnetStringToBstr(masterStore->Description);
 _CurrentMasterStore->put_Description(desc);

This is also causing memory leak.

Comment: I see that below line is causing the memory leak..
STDMETHODIMP CMasterStore::put_Description(BSTR newVal)
{

   fbstrDescription = newVal;
 return S_OK;
}

I have tried attach also.. fbstrDescription.Attach(newVal);

Still its leaking..

Comment: Thank you all for the help. the root cause here was reference count mismatch for masterrecord.
After createInstance, I have Addref() call and then QueryInterface() call.
AddRef() is also called by QueryInterface() internally. So, reference count was 2.
I was calling release() from the caller. But this was not deleting the object as there is still reference count.
Fix: After object is handed over to the caller, I have called release().